Whatsapp Business on IOS crashes after I connected it to the web application on a windows computer
The application will load for a little while and crash whenever I try to send a voicenote. It started after I tried linking it to a Windows whatsapp app on my computer.
Also whenever I open Whats app my Iphone 14 gets really hot.
I have since restarted my phone, unlinked the connection, updated whatsapp, updated my IOS, cleared the cache, offloaded the app, contacted whatsapp support (they suck), reinstaled whatsapp, and unconnected Icloud.
I am running out of ideas. Does any one know any way to debug the app to find the issue?
